# Can Snort be configured as HIDS?

Tags: ids, snort, hids

I need to give a presentation regarding Snort and Security Auditing. I have recently learned to configure Snort as a NIDS.
I want to know is there any way I can configure Snort as an HIDS? If I am updating variable HOME_NET to my IP, it'll log all ingress and egress traffic but is there a way to make it log all application and events occurring in a system?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: snort is a network analysis tool (https://www.snort.org/faq/what-is-snort)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Snort is not designed to *log all application and events occurring in a system*.  A HIDS is not just a NIDS limited to just one host; it's a separate and additional layer of protections that can only be performed locally (like looking at files, processes, logs, and user contexts).  Snort doesn't even try to do any of that.